# Unreadable text in Java

Tags: java, pdf, text

I'm reading text from a PDF file. I tried to print it in the console but it shows me unreadable text like:

> لا ضو ٦ُخش ٣ ،ٖ يٓ وِح، ٤ًق ٣ ل٘زٝ ج ُٜٔح ،ّ ٝ ه ُٜ حٓ ػ ٤ِٜ أ ٣لؼ ِٞج
>   ٝعٞف ٣ذٛؾٞ يٗ ذوذس ذشجػطٜ .ْ

I don't understand the text. but when I write it as a PDF file again, I can read the text because it backs to the normal. **The text is written in Arabic.**
Why I see the text like that? and **how to make it readable text**?

Comment: Directionality problem?

Comment: Historically, many Arabic PDF files were written in physical order instead of logical order. You need to detect the lines and manually reverse the characters to recover from this, it's a PITA.

Comment: Call me confused. Is it *supposed to be* Arabic, or not?

Comment: @bmargulies are all code points in Arabic in the BMP?

Comment: Yes they are all in the BMP. The OP should clarify; I read his question as expecting Arabic but not seeing readable arabic.

Comment: @bmargulies: funny, I understood is as the exact opposite: "The text is written in Arabic. Why I see the text like that?" points to a possible decoding problem, e.g., from "readable" text *to* this set of Arabic characters.

Comment: @ImZaaat If you want help, please edit your question to also contain the relevant code (preferably a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://www.sscce.org/)) and (a link to) a sample PDF to illustrate your issue.